# Error log after installing Aschroder Custom Order Number

Tags: magento-1.9, error, error-log

I installed Aschroder Custom Order Number extension, and it seems like everything works properly. However, I'm getting this error in my system.log file. Can someone please help me understand how to fix it?

The error repeats, so I'm gonna pass only few first lines here.

```
2015-02-06T08:14:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 104: parser error : Comment not terminated 
&lt;!--          &lt;block type=&quot;paypal/logo&quot; name=&quot;paypal.p  in /home5/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2015-02-06T08:14:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             &lt;!--    &lt;action method=&quot;setLogoType&quot;&gt;&lt;value&gt;wePrefer_150x60&lt;/value&gt;&lt;  in /home5/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2015-02-06T08:14:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():               ^  in /home5/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a section commented out in a layout xml file but it's not closed.  A comment starts with `<!--` and ends with with `-->`.  It should be pretty easy to track down.  Search the contents of your theme's layout folder for "wePrefer_150x60" and you'll find your open ended comment that's throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I found the file. It's paypal.xml

Comment: I tried to comment out the code that renders paypal buttons on the product page, but if I do it I get this error. I do't know why though, because I always close the comment. This file originally looks commented out from line 104 till the end.

Comment: You may be better off backing up the file and just completely removing the xml that you don't want to show up.

Comment: I just renamed it to .old and it looks like everything works perfectly. I was afraid that if remove it I will completely turn off paypal as a payment option, but it seems like I didn't.